# isEqual not working, sorting array using nsnumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, compare

I have sorted the 2D data. the _BankNames and _Rates are the arrays being sorted, a part of code is as follows.

The sorted data is then required to update into the tableview. I am trying to change the text on tableview to N/A if the value is 0 and append % to the value if it is not zero.

But unfortunately, the isEqual function is not working inside the cellforRowAtIndexPath. The NSLog shows the value of _Rates[row] but I cannot compare it with the 0.

When I am not sorting the array, the 'isEqual' function works well. But I require to sort the numbers.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
 _BankNames = [sortedArray valueForKey:@"bankname"];
    _Rates = [sortedArray valueForKey:@"bankrate"];





 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  

//
    NSString *value = _Rates[row];

        if([value isEqual:@"0"])
        {
            cell.rate_label.text = @"N/A";
        }
         else
        {
            NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", _Rates
                                [row], @" %"];
            cell.rate_label.text = result;
        }

    NSLog(@"rate = %@", _Rates[row]); 
//

[21577:60b] rate = 2.5
2014-10-01 21:57:01.650 [21577:60b] rate = 2.5
2014-10-01 21:57:01.683 [21577:60b] rate = 2.5
2014-10-01 21:57:01.701 [21577:60b] rate = 1.5
2014-10-01 21:57:01.734 [21577:60b] rate = 0
2014-10-01 21:57:01.783 [21577:60b] rate = 0
2014-10-01 21:57:01.816 [21577:60b] rate = 0
2014-10-01 21:57:01.851 [21577:60b] rate = 0
2014-10-01 21:57:01.900 [21577:60b] rate = 0
2014-10-01 21:57:01.951 [21577:60b] rate = 0
2014-10-01 21:57:02.016 [21577:60b] rate = 0
2014-10-01 21:57:02.084 [21577:60b] rate = 0
2014-10-01 21:57:02.150 [21577:60b] rate = 0
2014-10-01 21:57:02.334 [21577:60b] rate = 2.5
2014-10-01 21:57:02.996 [21577:60b] rate = 2.5
2014-10-01 21:57:03.014 [21577:60b] rate = 2.5
```

Comment: The values in your `_Rates` array are numbers, not strings.

Comment: I have tried this,
        if([_Rates[row] isEqualToNumber: 0])
now I am having this error.
-[__NSCFNumber compare:]: nil argument

Comment: You need `if ([value isEqualToNumber:@0])`. `value` is an `NSNumber`. You need to compare it to another `NSNumber`. `0` is the same as `nil`. `@0` is an `NSNumber` with a value of 0.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy, +1 to you.
that works,
just replaced 0 with [NSNumber numberWithInt:0]

Comment: Use `@0` instead of `[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]`. Much easier to type and read.